# Zoom buttons in google maps not shown in Android

Tags: android, button, zooming, android-maps

does anybody know how the zoom buttons of google maps to programmatically appeared in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```